# Dropbox indicator menu went missing in 13.10. How to get it back?

Tags: dropbox, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 13.10, then installed Dropbox from Ubuntu Software Center. Yet starting Dropbox seems to have no effect, and the Dropbox icon doesn't appear in the top-right indicator area like it normally does. Dropbox is apparently running, but the indicator/menu doesn't show up.

Comment: Is `nautilus` running? The indicator for dropbox is a nautilus extension.